# C# WebApi ModelBinding Validation in custom property type of DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, validation, asp.net-web-api

I have a route in a controller with some model transferred. This model (DTO) contains a custom type property (eg. Password, zip-code, ...). I would like to add a ModelBinder like one described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to the Property Type (Password). !Not to the whole DTO!

The resulting model (DTO) definition should look like:

```cs
namespace UserService.Models.DTO
{
    public class UserRegisterDto
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Password Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When a JSON (eg. see below) is now transferred the Password property shall be automatically validated.

```json
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@mail.com",
    "password": "Test12345!"
}
```

The route implementation should look like that:

```cs
namespace UserService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/api/user/")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(UserRegisterDto request)
        {
            User? user = await this._userService.Register(request);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought I could implement something like the following but the validation does not work at all...

```
namespace UserService.Models
{
    [ModelBinder(typeof(PasswordEntityBinder))]
    public class Password
    {
        private const string PasswordRegex = "(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&?*\\\"§$\\/()=~]+)(?![.\\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$";

        #region Properties
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => Value;

        public static implicit operator string(Password e) => e.Value;

        public static bool TryParse(ReadOnlySpan<char> s, out Password? result)
        {
            result = null;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.ToString()))
                return false;

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(s.ToString(), PasswordRegex))
                return false;

            result = new Password()
            {
                Value = s.ToString(),
            };

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if there is any possibility to achieve a modelbinding to a type which is used as a property in a model (DTO)?

Comment: Would suggest FluentValidation for .NET which will do this very well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a further look for my question since I was not satisfied with using some 3rd party lib. I found a proper solution which allows me to use a custom complex type as for example int with validation and conversion at the same time. This solution works for asp.net net6.0. I use:

- A **System.Text.Json** JSON custom converter
- IValidatableObject

The json password is at first converted with the JSON converter and then validated.

The following shows the example, which can be applied to any type:

```cs
// Password.cs

namespace UserService.Models
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PasswordJsonConverter))]
    public class Password : IValidatableObject
    {
        private const string PasswordRegex = "(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&?*\\\"§$\\/()=~]+)(?![.\\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$";

        public string Value { get; set; } = "";

        public override string ToString() => Value;
        public static implicit operator string(Password e) => e.Value;

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Value))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Password may not be empty");
                yield break;
            }

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.Value, PasswordRegex))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Password invalid formatted");

        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// PasswordJsonConverter.cs

namespace UserService.Converter
{
    public class PasswordJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Password>
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            return (typeToConvert == typeof(Password));
        }

        public override Password? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            Password pw = new Password();
            string? pw_string;

            try
            {
                pw_string = reader.GetString();
            }catch(InvalidOperationException)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (pw_string == null)
                return null;

            pw.Value = pw_string;
            return pw;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Password value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to use the Password object in a DTO like any basic type. For example:

```cs
// RegisterDto.cs

namespace UserService.Models.DTO
{
    public class UserRegisterDto
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Password Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The input json would look like:

```json
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@mail.com",
    "password": "Test12345!"
}
```